# $a< \epsilon +b \Rightarrow a \leq (1-\delta) b$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

Let $a, b\in (0, \infty)$ be such that $a< \epsilon +b$ for all $\epsilon >0.$

> My Question: Can we find $\delta > 0$ such that $a\leq (1-\delta) b$?

Comment: I have answered below - $\delta$ depends on the relation between $a$ and $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

No. Since under the first condition, $a$ can be $a=b$, while $(1-\delta)b =b-\delta b < b$, since $\delta b<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What is the highest value allowed for $a$ by "$a< \epsilon +b$ for all $\epsilon >0$"?

Answer (score 0):

If it's $\epsilon<a<b$ then we can set $1-\delta:=\frac{a}{a-\epsilon}-h$ with $h>0$.

It's $a\le (1-\delta)b=(\frac{a}{a-\epsilon}-h)b$ and multiplicated with $\frac{a-\epsilon}{a}$ one gets $a-\epsilon\le (1-h\frac{a-\epsilon}{a})b<b$.

Because of $\delta>0$ and $1-\delta>0$ choose $\frac{\epsilon}{a-\epsilon}<h<\frac{a}{a-\epsilon}$.

For the trivial case $0<a\leq\epsilon$ choose $1-\delta\geq\frac{\epsilon}{b}$.

For $a\geq b$ exists of course no solution: $1-\delta <1$